# How to construct home page URL to render DetaiView with Django?

Tags: python, django

Please, help me to write correct URL to render context on the home page. 
Thanks to the kind help received here, I have the following code:

**model:**

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from django.db import models

class DayOfWeekSchedule(models.Model):
    “""Dynamic days of week"""
def days_of_week(self):
    days = {
        '1': _('Monday’), 
        '2': _('Tuesday’), 
        '3': _('Wednesday'), 
        '4': _('Thursday’), 
        '5': _('Friday'), 
        '6': _('Saturday'), 
        '7': _('Sunday')}
    DOW_CHOICES = []
    today = datetime.today()
    for i in range(7):
        day_number = (today + timedelta(days=i)).isoweekday()
        day = days[str(day_number)]
        DOW_CHOICES.append(day_number, day)
        context = dict(DOW_CHOICES)
        return context
```

**view:**

```
import datetime
from datetime import *
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from .models import DayOfWeekSchedule

class DayOfWeekSchedules(DetailView):
    model = DayOfWeekSchedule
    template_name = 'schedule.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DayOfWeekSchedules, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context_a = self.object.my_dict()
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

**url:**

```
path('<int:pk>/', DayOfWeekSchedules.as_view(), name='schedule’),
```

and I get on http://127.0.0.1:8000/ the Error 404. I would like to see my page on 127.0.0.1:8000, not on 127.0.0.1:8000/1/.

I also highly appreciate the relevant reading recommendations.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `DetailView`? A detail view is for showing the detail about one object. If you remove the pk from the URL, Django cannot automatically tell which object to display the detail for. Which object do you want to display the detail about on the homepage? Please show your `schedule.html`.

Comment: set your url     `path('', DayOfWeekSchedules.as_view(), name='schedule’)`

Comment: explaining @Alasdair answer, DetailView means you want to show details about an object so you must need `pk` or any unique field to represent that object and must pass to your url, like you did `path('<int:pk>/', DayOfWeekSchedules.as_view(), name='schedule’),` but if you want your home page like `path('', DayOfWeekSchedules.as_view(), name='schedule’)` this means you are showing list of all objects in your home page and should use ListView instead of DetailView.

Comment: No, I am not sure that I need DetailView.  I just wrote on a fragment of the whole task, which I have problem with right now.  I have no experience, and I am looking for my way by trying different solutions. If you can recommend me a better way to move ahead, I highly appreciate it.  Here is a fragment of my template. ‘c’ is a key of context dictionary.
   `…
  {% for c in context %}
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <td>
            Today {{ ‘c’ }}
          </td>
        </tr>
…
       </table>
…{% endfor %}
`